# Is there any way to get "good" Autocompletion in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I recently tried PhpStorm and it's great especially with the completion.

When I <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> (mac) I get suggestions that actually exist, like when I'm in a JS file and my project has jQuery I get Element Suggestions when typing `$("#`.

But in VS Code it feels like all suggestions come from AI and aren't even based on what is present in my project.

EDIT: Because I have difficulties describing what I mean I uploaded [this video](https://gfycat.com/adventurousrealisticanole) to help you understand my problem

Is there any way to get similar behavior in VS Code?

Comment: if you don't get the autocompletes you want write an extension that does

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to improve IDE suggestions, and that is by installing extensions for the particular programming language that you use.

So, based on the tags you added for your question, for PHP, you can install "PHP Intelephense", for jQuery you can install "jQuery Code Snippets" and for HTML install "HTML CSS Support".

You can very easily install all 3 extensions by clicking on the "Extensions" option on the left hand side of the IDE (little cubes).

Comment: `jQuery Code Snippets` doesn't help you if you are looking for `autocompletion/IntelliSense`

Comment: I already have those Extensions installed, I do get auto completion for the most time but like I said it rather feels like ai than suggestions based on the actual elements I have in my project.

Comment: I've now edited my Question with a Video showing what exactly I mean :)